# How to get unique values that uniquely belong a combination of values in other columns?

Tags: python

I cannot figure the code to write this and I appreciate all the help I can get.
Let's say I have the data frame below:

[EXAMPLE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmoIw.png)

I want to return all the values that belong to a unique combination of columns A and B. For example, Susan belongs to both combination of (N,N) and (N,Y) so I am not interested in that.
However, Bob and John are only associated with same combos on column A and B.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you fix how the data frame is printed?

Comment: What work has been done to solve this? Also if you want a mapping between every combination of A and B to values, you can use groupby or a dict where the key is the concatenated string from A and B.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that with pandas.DataFrame.groupby you can achieve something. Maybe you need to combine the values of columns A and B in one same column